# Combine multiple rows into one while transposing its column value into a single row

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Need any help on how I can achieve as in the image below.
I want to combine multiple rows of the same person into one while transposing the column value of the person into a single row. I would like to achieve doing it preferable via VBA but if not then by formula.

[image]

Sorry I don't have anything to show. I already have the codes to generate a unique list for the names but I don't know how to transpose the data in the respective columns. I don't have any idea on how to approach this problem. Seeking any guidance or even ideas.

```
Public Sub extractUniques(rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    rngSource.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        copytorange:=rngTarget, Unique:=True

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this!

```
Sub specialTransfer()
    Dim inp As Range, outp As Range, rng As Range, c As Range, data(), u, r, x, i, j

    Set inp = [A1] 'Change this to the top left cell of your input
    Set outp = [F1] 'Change this to the top left cell of your output
    Set rng = Range(inp.Offset(1, 1), Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))

    data = rng.Value

    Set u = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    For r = 1 To UBound(data)
        u(data(r, 1)) = Empty
    Next r
    x = u.Keys()

    'Option to clear out everything past the outputcell
    'Range(outp, Cells(Rows.Count, Columns.Count)).ClearContents

    outp = "Name"
    For i = 0 To u.Count - 1
        j = 1
        outp.Offset(i + 1) = x(i)
        For Each c In rng
            Range(outp.Offset(, j), outp.Offset(, j + 2)) = Array("Day", "Time out", "Time in")
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(c.Offset(, -1).Resize(, 4)) = 4 Then
                If c = x(i) Then
                    outp.Offset(i + 1, j).Value = Format(Mid(c.Offset(, -1), 4, 10), "General Number")
                    outp.Offset(i + 1, j + 1).Value = Format(c.Offset(, 1), "h:mm AM/PM")
                    outp.Offset(i + 1, j + 2).Value = Format(c.Offset(, 2), "h:mm AM/PM")
                    j = j + 3
                End If
            End If
        Next c
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: One moment. I'm trying it out.

Comment: Wow great man. It works. But it returns "12:00 AM" for output under "Day". Btw which is better in your opinion, for this kind of task, using VBA or formula? because I may have up to thousand of rows to process.

Comment: @AfdzalYunus I think it has to do with the pre-set numberformat in that cell, try changing the whole output columns for "Day" to General. This can happen if you moved the output sideways. Also you should have something for clearing out old values since this only overwrites what it can reach.. But I would always use VBA for this kind of operation, especially when the alternative is an array formula. And applied to that many rows it can get quite slow/heavy.

Comment: @AfdzalYunus See updated answer with formatting at runtime and clearing option. And fell free to Accept and or Up-vote if it works

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to accept and up-vote your answer for now but I definitely will once I can. Thank you for your code. I had to spent a couple of hours to learn about arrays and dictionary to understand it. However, I'm not comfortable with the use of `Offset` because I actually simplified the actual input table to ask this question. It is a table that has a lot of other columns that I left out and the columns is not actually side by side like in the question. I can though, however, pulls it out, run your code, then delete it. Hmmm.

Answer (score 0):

Hoping to be able to achieve it via VBA but don't think that I can. It's not the exact result I was hoping for but it works. Did it using array formula below.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX("table data",MATCH(1,("criteria1 column"="criteria1")*("criteria2 column"="criteria2")*("criteria3 column"<>""),0), "criteria3 colNum"),"")

Ctrl + Shift + Enter
```

[multiple row into one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkhxL.png)